# How to specify coupling in Pspice CAD?

Tags: inductor, coupling, pspice

I am doing PSpice CAD by simple schematic generation(not using netlist), I need to apply coupling and for this I need Coupling Component, but I do not know how to use that in schematic, I mean in netlist we have
K L1 L2 
but when I try to do that directly in CAD I get 
"Part L1 has no L1 property"
"Part L2 has no L1 property"
can somebody please tell me the real way to use this component directly through schematic (not using netlist)?

Comment: What do you mean when you say this: "in netlist we have K L1 L2"?

Comment: Some thing got missing I mean to say in net list we write
K(name) L(1st inductor name) L(2nd inductor name) coupling value

Comment: If it's anything like microcap then component "k" can be found - you need to search for this. In microcap it's located under something like "analogue primitives" from memory.

Comment: I think I got my problem, when I right click on component and go to the edit properties I can not enter values in L1 and L2 for coupling, is there something that I can do ?

Comment: Coupling is a number between 0 and 1 where 1 represents total coupling and 0 represents 0 magnetic coupling. L1 L2 needs to be enetered in a different place.

Comment: Coupling value I am able to get 0.99 but the problem is I can not enter value in L1 and L2 of K(Coupling) it does not allow me to enter value in these fields, so I think system is not able to decide which inductors to couple, can you please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: http://denkenblog.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/mutual-inductance-in-pspice-schematics.html

Comment: I can produce a formal answer based on the above but I need to know if the link I left in the comment above was useful for solving the problem. Maybe you should formally answer this question - it's quite a useful Q and A really.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I encountered was not a technical one but one that is more of a layout based

[image: Edit Property Window]

we need to change in this Property window at the given location, I do not know the reason but that is what worked for me :)